# "WHERE" Statement From Another Table

Tags: sql

I have a table of following/followers that has 3 fields:

`id , FollowingUserName,FollowedUserName`

And I have a table with posts:

```
id,Post,PublishingUsername
```

And I need a query which returns certain fields from post

but the "where" will be where:

- The `PublishingUsernam` From The Posts Will Match The `FollowedUserName` From The `Following/Followers` Table
- And The `FollowingUserName` Will Be The Logged On UserName.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To just get posts:

```
select p.* from posts p where p.PublishingUsername in 
(select FollowedUsername from followers)
and p.PublishingUsername = LOGGEDINUSER
```

Or you could use a join:

```
select p.* from posts p
left join followers f on f.PublishingUsername = p.PublishingUsername
and p.publishingUsername = LOGGENINUSER
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to do a [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) it looks like.  Basically, you want to select from your post table where the publishing username = followed user name, and where followingusername = loggedin name.

Just taking a stab (since I don't have an SQL server here right now), but it might look like:

`SELECT * FROM Posts INNER JOIN Following ON Posts.PublishingUsername = Following.FollowedUserName WHERE FollowingUserName = LoggedInName`

Answer (score 0):

Without `JOIN` you can:

```
SELECT * FROM Posts p, Followers f
WHERE
    f.FollowingUserName = 'LoggedInUserName' 
    AND f.FollowedUserName = p.PublishingUsername
```

Comment: Question about SQL - would the above statement actually result in an implicit JOIN?  It seems like it would, even if it's not specified.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 'fields'    
FROM TABLE1 INNER JOIN TABLE2 
ON TABLE1.FollowedUserName = TABLE2.PublishingUsername
WHERE FollowingUserName = 'myvalue'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using cleaner Join Syntax**

```
SELECT *
FROM following f
JOIN posts p ON p.PublishingUsername = f.FollowedUsername
AND f.FollowingUserName = LOGGED_IN;
```